# printing html in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

What's the best way for print html?

I can do this:

```
container.InnerHtml = "<input type=\"text\" ...runat=..>";
```

where `container` is an ref to  an `<div>` HTML

but I have impression that this it's not the correct mode.
can someone point me for right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it's not usual but if it works is ok as well depending on your specific needs.

but if your content like: `"<input type=\"text\" ...runat=..>"` is fixed and known, why don't you add the control(s) directly in the page at design time, in the markup?

Comment: Do you want it pretty formatted? Coloring, spaces, etc? Or just raw?

Comment: `runat="server"` won't work if injected in that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Paolo has mentioned, using the `<asp:PlaceHolder>` is a good way to inject HTML at runtime. Not only does it allow for you to output plain html `<div><p>Hello World!</p></div>` but it also allows you to dynamically add other asp.net controls.

For your example above you could do

.aspx

```
<asp:PlaceHolder id="PlaceHolder1" runat="server" />
```

c#

```
TextBox textBox1 = new TextBox();
textBox1.Id = "textBox1";
textBox1.TextMode = TextBoxMode.SingleLine;

PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(textBox1);
```

This then allows you to access the value which you enter into textBox1 dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

if by "printing HTML" you mean injecting it at runtime in a ASP.NET webform, you may try using a [PlaceHolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.placeholder.aspx)